# Why is it bad to pause/abort threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, parallel-processing

My model of how threads work is that some `ThreadManager` gives each thread a turn.  When it's a thread's turn, it gets to execute a few lines of code.

To pause a thread, couldn't one just have the `ThreadManager` (momentarily) stop allowing that thread to have a turn?

To abort a thread, couldn't the `ThreadManager` just never give that thread another turn?

What's the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) about pausing threads:

> You have no way of knowing what code a
>   thread is executing when you suspend
>   it. If you suspend a thread while it
>   holds locks during a security
>   permission evaluation, other threads
>   in the AppDomain might be blocked. If
>   you suspend a thread while it is
>   executing a class constructor, other
>   threads in the AppDomain that attempt
>   to use that class are blocked.
>   Deadlocks can occur very easily.

Aborted thread can lead to unpredicted circumstances. There is a good article about this: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2009/03/13/ManagedCodeAndAsynchronousExceptionHardening.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Alex, but to elaborate further, if you need to "pause" a thread, it will probably be better to look at some sort of locking mechanism like Semaphores, Mutexes, or one of the many other ones available.

But, without knowing your code, Windows is a preemptive multitasking environment. Usually this is not needed, just let your threads run and the underlying OS and scheduler will make sure all your tasks get a fair turn.